# Android draw text into rectangle on center and crop it if needed

Tags: android, text, draw, rect

I want to draw text into rectangle on center (horizontally and vertically). If there is too much of a text that crop it what do not fit into rect.

I have try to do it as [this example show](http://b.ivity.asia/2010/12/29/using-android-text-staticlayout/), but without luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this, it is some what same as what you need, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285510/how-to-overlay-image-with-multiline-texttext-will-be-in-center-of-the-canvas/13287621#13287621

Comment: Try this, it's work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120392/android-center-text-on-canvas

Comment: This work for me, try it. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120392/android-center-text-on-canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120392/android-center-text-on-canvas)

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
private void drawRectText(String text, Canvas canvas, Rect r) {

    textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    int width = r.width();

    int numOfChars = textPaint.breakText(text,true,width,null);
    int start = (text.length()-numOfChars)/2;
    canvas.drawText(text,start,start+numOfChars,r.exactCenterX(),r.exactCenterY(),textPaint);
}
```

Comment: This draws text with align center but only horizontally. So the question is how to do it vertically also.

Answer (score 5):

this function worked for me.

```
private void drawDigit(Canvas canvas, int textSize,  float cX, float cY, int color, String text) {
        Paint tempTextPaint = new Paint();
        tempTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        tempTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        tempTextPaint.setColor(color); 
        tempTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize); 

        float textWidth = tempTextPaint.measureText(text);
        //if cX and cY are the origin coordinates of the your rectangle 
        //cX-(textWidth/2) = The x-coordinate of the origin of the text being drawn 
        //cY+(textSize/2) =  The y-coordinate of the origin of the text being drawn 

        canvas.drawText(text, cX-(textWidth/2), cY+(textSize/2), tempTextPaint);
    }
```