# Osmdroid insert text inside marker

Tags: android, osmdroid

How I can insert text inside [Osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) marker? Suppose i need place several markers on map, and each marker should have number inside it. [image] How I can make it? I try `#setTitle()` method, but it place text in balloon.

Update:

```
for(int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
    mOrderPoint = orders.get(i).getStart();
    final Order order = orders.get(i);
    Marker orderMarker = new Marker(mMap);
    orderMarker.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.order_pin));
    orderMarker.setPosition(mOrderPoint);
}
```

Comment: what you needed xactly..? you need something same as the image you have attached with the question?

Comment: Yes, but number inside icon should be different for each marker

Comment: please add some code you have tried..

Comment: what is the problem you are facing while using settitle method?

Comment: When I use setTitle method, number added to balloon and show only on click, but I need number inside icon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method takes a drawable from your resources, draws some text on top of it and returns the new drawable. All you need to do is give it the resource id of your bubble, and the text you want on top. Then you can pass the returned drawable wherever you want it.

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```

Note:

To preserve density you need this constructor

```
BitmapDrawable (Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)
```

So, keeping your context, last return should be something like

```
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
```

This prevent an undesired resized drawable.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at osmdroid bonus pack.

Website: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

There are many examples of stylized bubbles with text in it.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Blue_Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090042/15017966) does **not work with vector drawables in Kotlin**. The reason is due to `BitmapFactory`: it returns an error.

If you are programming in kotlin, there is a significantly simpler solution than using `BitmapFactory`.

Firstly, get the drawable:

```kotlin
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.order_pin)!!
```

Then simply use the `toBitmap()` function:

```kotlin
val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap()
```

And then the rest of the solution is effectively the same.

Final code:

```kotlin
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.order_pin)!!
val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap()

val paint = Paint(); 
paint.style = Style.FILL  
paint.color = Color.BLACK 
paint.textSize = 20 

val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
// Note, this code places the text in the center of the Bitmap (both vertically and horizontally)
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121873
canvas.drawText(text, bm.width / 2f,
                    bm.height / 2f - (paint.descent() + paint.ascent() / 2), paint)

val iconWithText = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, bitmap)

// Marker has to be initialised somewhere in your code
marker.icon = iconWithText
```

Of course, this code if for one time use. If you want to move it to a function, the parameter could either be the drawable or drawableID, and it would return the `icon`:

```kotlin
return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, bitmap)
```