# Get size of Canvas before API 16

Tags: android

The documentation says about **Canvas.getHeight()**:

> Returns the height of the current drawing layer

Is this as much the case for API < 16?

**Example:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

class MyView extends View {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(20, 40);
        params.leftMargin = 50;
        params.topMargin = 50;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        Log.d("me", "canvas.getHeight = " + canvas.getHeight());
        Log.d("me", "canvas.getWidth = " + canvas.getWidth());
        canvas.getClipBounds(r);
        Log.d("me", ".getClipBounds.height() = " + r.height());
        Log.d("me", ".getClipBounds.widht() = " + r.width());
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(this);
        container.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        container.addView(new MyView(this));
        setContentView(container);
    }
}
```

**API >= 16:**

If I am using an emulator like Galaxy Nexus with API 16 or above **canvas.getHeight()** returns 40, as expected:

```
D/me﹕ canvas.getHeight = 40
D/me﹕ canvas.getWidth = 20
D/me﹕ .getClipBounds.height() = 40
D/me﹕ .getClipBounds.widht() = 20
```

**API < 16:**

But If I am using an emulator like Galaxy Nexus with API 15 or below (also tried this with a real device and API 7):

```
D/me﹕ canvas.getHeight = 1280
D/me﹕ canvas.getWidth = 720
D/me﹕ .getClipBounds.height() = 40
D/me﹕ .getClipBounds.widht() = 20
```

**Question:**

Why are the results different? I could not find any hint in the documentation.