# Android Animation - Scale up and Fade along with Background Transition

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to do something like this.. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Right now, i am using a Scale Animation and FadeOut Animation. It looks like this..

[image]

How do i add background colour to this.. Also please keep in mind that i want this to work from ICS/Jellybean

My code till now...

fade_out_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.1"
        android:duration="100" />
</set>
```

scale_up_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0.1"
        android:fromYScale="0.1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

activity_main.xml - just the relevant part

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="004"
                android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/outer_view"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_yellow"/>


      </RelativeLayout>
```

shape_circle.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="@color/ash" />  <!-- Fill color -->

            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/medium_gray" /> <!-- Outerline color -->

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/ash" />  <!-- Fill color -->

            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/yellow" /> <!-- Outerline color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/ash" />  <!-- Fill color -->

            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/yellow" /> <!-- Outerline color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/ash" />  <!-- Fill color -->

            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/yellow" /> <!-- Outerline color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

shape_circle_yellow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke android:color="@color/yellow"
        android:width="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Java code:

```
 textView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final View view2 = findViewById(R.id.outer_view);

                Animation scale_up_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.scale_up_animation);
                final Animation fade_out_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out_animation);

                scale_up_animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        view2.startAnimation(fade_out_animation);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                fade_out_animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        view2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                view2.startAnimation(scale_up_animation);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post shape_circle_yellow.xml??

Comment: @sJy, updated the question

Comment: Could you check the answer & see whether that works??

Comment: Will update in a day

Comment: @Vamsi Challa:- let me know is it proper or not https://imgflip.com/gif/1eocdx

Comment: Another effect-> https://imgflip.com/gif/1eod9k

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most simple way to reach this effect on Android is to create few custom views. 
For example we can divide animation into **two views** (according to divide to conquer rule). First view let's name `CircleButton`. It will be button which can be in two states - default and selected.

[image: State default]
[image: State selected]

Second view let's name `CircularRippleEffect` and it will be container for animation during state changing.

[image: Circular Ripple Effect here]

When we combine this views together we will obtain effect like this:

[image: Final effect]

So, The question is how to create `CircleButton` and `CircularRippleEffect` classes ;)
The first one is simple. We should extend `View` class and `Override` `onDraw` method. In onDraw method we have to draw two circles (first is representing button background and second is yellow border).
Our onDraw method will look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, backgroundPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, borderPaint);
    drawCenter(canvas, textPaint, text);
}
```

We have to remember that our `backgroundPaint`should have set style up as `FILL` by using method `backgroundPaint.setStyle(FILL);` and our `borderPaint` should have style `STROKE`. I set also proper colors for this `Paint` objects. The last thing we should do in `onDraw` method is drawing text on the center of the View.
I've created `drawCenter()` method for this implementation, that can be found in this answer from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/32081250/1722808

And that is all we should know about `CircleButton` class. Everything else is similar to every custom view.

The `CircularRippleEffect` class is more complicated. We also draw two circles, but we have to animate them smoothly. That is why the size of every shape depends on a progress value.

OnDraw method from this class looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    tempCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    tempCanvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, outerCircleRadiusProgress * maxCircleSize, circlePaint);
    tempCanvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, innerCircleRadiusProgress
                * (maxCircleSize + ADDITIONAL_SIZE_TO_CLEAR_ANTIALIASING), maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Implementing this is a little tricky. I've used

```
tempCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

because I wanted to obtain circle with transparent area inside. And to reach this effect we have to create tempCanvas and tempBitmap. 
Similar implementation here: [Android canvas: draw transparent circle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image)

The last step is combining this views together (we can do it in FrameLayout) and change state of this views in the same time when user clicks it.
The whole source code you can find on my github account  https://github.com/ljarka/CircleAnimation

Comment: Most of the answers were good.. but this one came close the most.

Answer (score 4):

[Have a look at this](https://imgflip.com/gif/1eod9k),

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
         case R.id.textView4:
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_circle));
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgrey));

            scale_up_animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    view2.startAnimation(fade_out_animation);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            fade_out_animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    view2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_yellow));
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_600));
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            view2.startAnimation(scale_up_animation);
            break;
```

**circle_yellow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval"
       android:tint="@color/yellow_100">
       <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/yellow_600" />
       <solid android:color="@color/grey_500" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set background to the TextView, change your selector `android:state_selected` like below.

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#81fde980" />  <!-- Fill color -->
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/yellow" /> <!-- Outerline color -->
    </shape>
</item>
```

Now update `onAnimationEnd()` of `scale_up_animation` as

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    view2.startAnimation(fade_out_animation);
    if(textView4.isSelected()) {
        textView4.setSelected(false);
        textView4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));
    } else {
        textView4.setSelected(true);                                                    
        textView4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine even if you add the code to onAnimationStart() method

Answer (score 1):

Implement the code in your activity to make some animation

```
private View mContentView;
private View mLoadingView;
private int mShortAnimationDuration;

...

private void crossfade() {

    // Set the content view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
    // (but fully transparent) during the animation.
    mContentView.setAlpha(0f);
    mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
    // listener set on the view.
    mContentView.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)
            .setListener(null);

    // Animate the loading view to 0% opacity. After the animation ends,
    // set its visibility to GONE as an optimization step (it won't
    // participate in layout passes, etc.)
    mLoadingView.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}
```

Use this code for any components to fade in xml

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <fade>
  <targets>
  <target android:targetClass="android.widget.TextView" />
  <target android:targetClass="android.widget.FrameLayout" />
  <target android:targetClass="android.widget.LinearLayout" />
  <target android:targetClass="android.widget.ImageView" />
  </targets>
  </fade>

  </transitionSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cute view animation collection:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

you can use an animation like TakingOffAnimator or ZoomOutAnimator on custom shape or views with white background, and with a delay play same animation on a gray view that positioned in center of the first shape or view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(sizingAnimation);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```