# Prevent canvas from disjoining drawn text

Tags: android, canvas, text

I am trying to draw grid of numbers into a canvas.

```
val textX = x * TILE_SIZE + TILE_SIZE / 2f
val textY = y * TILE_SIZE + TILE_SIZE / 2f 
canvas.drawText(number.toString(), textX, textY, textPaint)
```

This is my paint

```
private val textPaint: Paint by lazy {
    Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = false
        color = Color.WHITE
        textSize = TILE_SIZE * 0.1f
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }
}
```

But the canvas keeps disjointing my text and aligns it in a non regular grid. I double checked my position values. Is there something I am missing?

[image]

edit: I am aware I have alignment set to CENTER, but if you notice, the text in the 4th row has higher offset then in the previous row

I was able to resolve the text disjointing by adding a subPixelText flag, interestingly, when i set paints flag strikeThroughText

```
isStrikeThruText = true
```

I get following result:

[image]

This, I believe this shows that the coordinates are set properly but there might be some issue with the paint configuration due to the font size.

Comment: You should look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120392/android-center-text-on-canvas . As answered the texts' baseline is placed on the coordinate you give it which causes it to be above the center of the cell. To truly center the text you should add some more to the Y coordinate depending on the text size.

Comment: Thanks, I have encountered this solution, but it doesn't resolve the disjointing and the vertical offset, in fact the problem persists even on the x-axis

Comment: Probably the problem is in the x and y calculations. You should add the code where you calculate x and y.

Comment: x and y are int values from loop: for (x in 0 untill columnCount) and so on

Comment: what does `Paint#getTextWidths(String text, float[] widths)` return in `widths` array? `Log.d` the content of that array

Comment: Then what is number? For example: for 807 are you drawing 807 all at once or first 8 then 0 then 7?

Comment: @pskink Interesting, sometimes it returns [1f, 2f, 1f]

Comment: @VeselinTodorov number is 807, 1003 etc.

Comment: and what about `Paint#measureText(String text)`?

Comment: @pskink it corresponds with sum of text widths

Comment: so `Paint#measureText()` returns 4? 4 = 1 + 2 + 1

Comment: @pskink Yes it does

Comment: Ok I might have a solution on the text disjointing, after setting             isSubpixelText = true, each number now has equal width. This makes sense, since the text is really small.

Answer (score 0):

There were two separate issues I have managed to solve:

1. Text disjointment - this was caused by having very small text, the result was that single letter has sometimes taken up too much space and shifted the next letter. Solution to this is changing paint [subpixelText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#isSubpixelText()) attribute:

   ```
   isSubpixelText = true
   ```
2. Text misposition - after looking into [Paint.FontMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html) I have realized that the `ascent` and `descent` values are recommended values set by the font and can be thus changed only within specified paint font. I solved this simply by switching to another font.

Edit: I ended up using [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html), more on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779934/how-is-staticlayout-used-in-android)