# Drawing Canvas with fixed scale

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have a button which is drawn using canvas `onDraw` method. The button itself may will change size depending on device, but I want the text I'm drawing inside to remain consistent, even with different screen size or font size user may have set in settings. That is why I'm doing it in pixels.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // 1. draw background
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(colorBg);
    canvas.drawRect(padding, padding, w-padding, h-padding, paint);

    // 2. draw border
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(colorBorder);
    canvas.drawRect(padding, padding, w-padding, h-padding, paint);

    // 3. draw text
    int fontSizeTextNew = canvas.getHeight() / 100 * 19;
    int fontSizePaddingNew = canvas.getHeight() / 100 * 19;

    textPaint.setTextSize(fontSizeTextNew);
    textPaint.setShader(blackShader);
    textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    textPaint.getTextBounds(
            prefTitle, // text
            0, // start
            prefTitle.length(), // end
            rectangle // bounds
    );

    canvas.drawText(
            prefTitle,
            canvas.getWidth()/2,
            Math.abs(rectangle.height()) + padding + fontSizePaddingNew,
            textPaint
    );

    // 4. draw icon
    int fontSizeIconNew = canvas.getHeight() / 100 * 55;
    String str = prefIcon;
    textPaint.setTypeface(awesomeFont);
    textPaint.setTextSize(fontSizeIconNew);
    textPaint.setShader(yellowShader);
    // center for the text
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120392/android-center-text-on-canvas
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;
    canvas.drawText(
            str,
            canvas.getWidth()/2,
            Math.abs(yPos) + fontSizeIconPadding,
            textPaint
    );
}
```

This 19% looks nice right now but it will look different on variouse screens. What is your approach to this problem? how you would solvethis problem?

[Button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWHsI.png) This is how it may look

Comment: use dp instead of pixel
it will look same in most devices

Comment: @ShayanD it will change based on settings. For example in Galaxy phones there is a option to adjust font size or screen size and it looks different

Comment: The user should be able to change the dimension of the display/content/font, so there isn't any direct way to do this. You can reuse YOUR code but you have to change HOW MANY pixels to draw and it should depend of display pixels size. So you have to compute the Real size of the display (in pixels) and then recompile your needed dimensions.

Comment: @emandt I am going to provide those configurations in local settings. But I already have my button size. is not this enough? why would I care for external dimensions

Comment: no if You use SP it will change based on settings

Comment: or you can use `context.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi/DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT` as a scale and multiply it to your font size

Comment: @ShayanD can I please create chat with you? I have a major problem understanding this concept

Comment: @AkakiGabisonia yes