# How To Show Progress In Percentage For All Files

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How can I implement a progress bar that will show the progress download of all files in percentage from 0% to 100% (all files). This is how my async looks like:

```
    public class DownloadFileFromFTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public DownloadFileFromFTP(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
         this.progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            this.progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    //code to list ftp files

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (this.progressDialog != null) {
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56628193/2099413..may be this can help

Answer (score 1):

Its should be

```
   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      this.progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    }
```

Comment: This method is not being called in my activity

Log.d("LOG", "update: " +values[0]); <- No log cat

also I had to change it to:
progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(values[0])));