# How to use ProgressBar in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created an app where a service runs in the background. When there is progress it will display a toast message, but I want to add a progress bar. Can someone helo me with this?

this is the method which will display the toast message: ( 25% downloaded, 50% and so on)

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            Log.d("Downloading files",
                    String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

layout of progress bar in activity_main.xml

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/p_barr"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progress="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I want to add the progressBar instead of the toast message. I am pretty new to the android studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a ProgressBar example with percentage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627616/how-to-show-a-progressbar-example-with-percentage-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple in your main activity.do

```
ProgressBar bar; 
// in oncreate method
bar=findviewbyid("your progressbar id p_barr ");
bar.setProgress(int);
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you