# Centering and Autosizing Text in Rect

Tags: java, android

I have a rectangle that I want to draw text inside. I want the text to be centered vertically and horizontally and I need the text size to changed to fit all characters inside the rectangle. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void drawFixedText(String text, Rect rect, Paint paint) {
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    int cX = rect.left;
    int cY = rect.top;

    float textSize = paint.getTextSize();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);

    float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);

    while (textWidth > rect.width())  {
        textSize--;
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    //if cX and cY are the origin coordinates of the your rectangle 
    //cX-(textWidth/2) = The x-coordinate of the origin of the text being drawn 
    //cY+(textSize/2) =  The y-coordinate of the origin of the text being drawn 

    canvas.drawText(text, cX-(textWidth/2), cY+(textSize/2), paint);
}
```

I tried to combine the answers from [Calculate text size according to width of text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area) and [Android draw text into rectangle on center and crop it if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512512/android-draw-text-into-rectangle-on-center-and-crop-it-if-needed)

But it didn't work in that the text is placed to the left of the rectangle instead of inside of it. How can I fix this?

Comment: `cX` is the left side of your `Rect`, so you don't want to subtract half the text width from that. Rather, you want to subtract it from the horizontal midpoint of the `Rect`; i.e., `rect.centerX() - (textWidth / 2)`. Also, you need to measure the text width each time after changing the size; that is, `textWidth = paint.measureText(text);` should be inside the loop, too, after the `setTextSize()` call.

Comment: Ok so I did this and it has moved the text seemingly over the top left corner of the rectangle

Comment: Uh, no, that's where it would be with the code you've posted. If you change the x-coordinate as I suggested, the text should be centered on the top side of the `Rect`. Make sure your build is up to date. That is, clean and rebuild after the changes. Also, I just noticed you want it centered vertically, too, so you need to do something similar for the y-coordinate, though using the text size won't center it exactly, if that's a concern.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the problem. My problem was that my text was being centered (Paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)) when I was calling this method (i.e. why it appeared to be far left). So after fixing that, it centered correctly

Comment: Ah, good catch. Yeah, I was assuming a default `Paint` object.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help! If you post an answer with the updated code like stated I will accept it as the answer

Comment: I made a slight correction to the vertical centering, so it's more exact. I'd forgotten `drawText()`'s y-coordinate is the text's baseline. Just FYI. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to measure the text width after each time setting its size. Otherwise, you'll end up with an infinite loop if the text starts out wider than the `Rect`.

```
while (textWidth > rect.width())  {
    textSize--;
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
}
```

Then, to center the text horizontally, you want to subtract half of the text width from the horizontal midpoint of the `Rect`, not from its left edge, which is what `cX` will be in your snippet. That is, replace `cX - (textWidth / 2)` with `rect.centerX() - (textWidth / 2)` in the `drawText()` call.

Furthermore, to center the text vertically, we'll need to do something similar with the y-coordinate. However, using the text size for that will not give the correct result. We need to measure the text's actual height and offset from baseline, which we can do using the `Paint#getTextBounds()` method.

Altogether, these changes would give something like:

```
public void drawFixedText(String text, Rect rect, Paint paint) {
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    float textSize = paint.getTextSize();
    float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);

    while (textWidth > rect.width())  {
        textSize--;
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
    }

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    canvas.drawText(text,
                    rect.centerX() - textWidth / 2,
                    rect.centerY() - (bounds.top + bounds.bottom) / 2,
                    paint);
}
```

Please note that this assumes a default `Paint` instance. That is, any properties that affect text alignment have their default values going into this method.